# postgreSQL error: "ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: NULL"

Tags: database

I'm new to SQL. I have a table with a column of **numeric**  type that include NULL values. I built the table structure in postgresql, when I try to import my table I get the following error:

`ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: NULL`

I tried both

`UPDATE MY_TABLE  SET MY_COLUMN = CAST(NULL AS NUMERIC)`

and setting manually the default value of the column as NULL, but none of them are working.
Is there another way to handle this problem?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! We only deal with questions about bionformatics here and this looks like a very standard SQL question with no connection to bioinformatics so I am afraid it is off topic. That said, I suspect you just want `UPDATE MY_TABLE  SET MY_COLUMN = NULL`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about SQL and not related to bioinformatics.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.